# How to sign a transaction hash in PHP?

Tags: php

Given the following example hash: `1ee917ec6ab6339e563d55abee50a49ccdb7d827cf087c0884f3da3b86e0dff4`, and the following example private key: `483F2F5445D97B948A61C0D58CCC438126F3746220556942662B999178E8A0C4`, how can I sign the transaction in PHP?

Comment: https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for the actual process without using a library of some sort.

Comment: Do you want a description of how signing works in general or specific code implementing signing in PHP (aka an ECDSA implementation in PHP)?

Comment: Hi, I already understood the process. I'm looking for specific code implementation as I failed to achieve it myself.